# Greensock in annyang command

Tags: timeline, gsap, annyang

I'm quite a newbie with annyang. I'm trying to add a Greensock Timeline in a annyang command, but it is not working. I am wondering if it is not possible or if I'm doing something wrong.

This is the code were it is about:

```js
var tlcrocodile = new TimelineLite({paused:true});
if (annyang) { 
  var commands = {
    'hello': function() {
      tlcrocodile.to(".crocodile_1", 0.3 , {x:+40} , 0);
    }
  };

  annyang.addCommands(commands);

  annyang.start();
}
```

Hopefully someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Ilse

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your `TimelineLite` instance never play because you instantiate it as paused but you never call [play()](https://greensock.com/docs/TimelineMax/play) on it.

Try instantiating it directly inside the `hello` command, when you need it to play.
And add a console log to make sure your command was really triggered.

```
if (annyang) {
    var commands = {
        'hello': function() {
            console.log('Hello command executed.');
            new TimelineLite().to(".crocodile_1", 0.3 , {x:+40} , 0);
        }
    };

    annyang.addCommands(commands);

    annyang.start();
}
```

Comment: Ah that fixed the problem! Thank you!